# How do I get Spyder to launch after Catalina update with fresh anaconda install?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, spyder, macos-catalina

I've been using Anaconda spyder (Python 3.7) on MacOS Catalina for about the past 3-4 weeks for a project I have been working on. However, I have noticed that after clicking launch on the navigator that Spyder won't launch. I have tried a clean install of anaconda using both pkg installer and command line installer. To uninstall I use anaconda-clean.

If anyone has ran into this issue and has found a solution please let me know. I would also accept a similar development environment that has a good object inspector like Spyder.

Comment: Any error messages, warnings, etc?

Comment: Nope, just hangs :/

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line? If nothing helps, you might want to give some Linux Distro like Ubuntu a shot and execute it in a virtual machine.

Comment: Had the same issue, nothing worked except for running Spyder from command line, then it suddenly started to work again on its own

Comment: I even tried running it from command line and that didn't work. I even manually reinstalled all of its dependencies

Comment: @KevinPatrick Did you find a solution? I have the same issue at the moment.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I followed the guide from https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/